# Dificuldade em criar coluna de soma no mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou fazendo um relatório de comissão, mas surgiu uma dúvida, quero trazer alguns totais no final do relatório como por exemplo o valor bruto de todas as comissoes, que seria o `vl_comis - desc_comis`. Enfim, como faço para criar uma coluna chamada `total_valor_bruto` que retornasse a soma de todos os valores brutos da tabela comissoes?

```
SELECT 
a.id,
a.nf,
a.data_lcto,
a.data_prog,
a.data_pgto,
a.vl_comis,
a.desc_comis,
a.ir_comis, 
a.vl_pgto,
a.pedido_comis,
b.Empresa as emp,
b.RazaoSocial as razao,
c.cod, 
c.Representante as representante,
d.PeriodoID as periodo_comissao,
d.Periodo_inicial as inicial,
d.Periodo_final as final
FROM (((Comissoes a
INNER JOIN Empresas b ON a.EmpresaID = b.EmpresaID)
INNER JOIN Representantes c ON a.RepresentanteID = c.RepresentanteID)
INNER JOIN Periodos d ON a.PeriodoID = d.PeriodoID)
WHERE d.PeriodoID ='".$_COOKIE["cpr"]."' ORDER BY a.created");
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro tem que colocar o cálculo que você quer que seja feito na consulta `(a.vl_comis - a.desc_comis) as total_valor_bruto` com a função `sum` que é para somar todos os resultados e colocar o `group by` para agregar os resultados nas colunas que não tem cálculo.

```
SELECT 
  a.id,
  a.nf,
  a.data_lcto,
  a.data_prog,
  a.data_pgto,
  a.vl_comis,
  a.desc_comis,
  a.ir_comis, 
  a.vl_pgto,
  a.pedido_comis,
  b.Empresa as emp,
  b.RazaoSocial as razao,
  c.cod, 
  c.Representante as representante,
  d.PeriodoID as periodo_comissao,
  sum(a.vl_comis - a.desc_comis) as total_valor_bruto,
  d.Periodo_inicial as inicial,
  d.Periodo_final as final
FROM (((Comissoes a
INNER JOIN Empresas b ON a.EmpresaID = b.EmpresaID)
INNER JOIN Representantes c ON a.RepresentanteID = c.RepresentanteID)
INNER JOIN Periodos d ON a.PeriodoID = d.PeriodoID)
WHERE d.PeriodoID ='".$_COOKIE["cpr"]."'
GROUP BY
  a.id,
  a.nf,
  a.data_lcto,
  a.data_prog,
  a.data_pgto,
  a.vl_comis,
  a.desc_comis,
  a.ir_comis, 
  a.vl_pgto,
  a.pedido_comis,
  b.Empresa,
  b.RazaoSocial,
  c.cod, 
  c.Representante,
  d.PeriodoID,
  d.Periodo_inicial,
  d.Periodo_final
ORDER BY
  a.created;
```

Comment: Sem o group by ele até que retorna o valor bruto mas só 1 registro, com o group by está dando esse erro: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY a.id, a.nf, a.data_lcto, a.data_prog, a.data_pgto, a.vl_comis, a.desc_c' at line 25

Comment: Você copiou a query do seu código e esqueceu de tirar o `);` do final, por isso me confundi. agora deve estar OK.

Comment: Essa resposta te ajudou @SmokeRohden, se sim aceita ela conforme mostra nessa [imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem a pergunta basta usar o seguinte query e alterar para o seu uso:

`select sum(a.vl_comis + a.ir_comis) as total_valor_bruto`

Se não for esta a resposta, me explique um pouco melhor por favor?